# How to get only active alias ip by ioctl?

Tags: c++, linux, networking, interface, ioctl

In the file "/etc/network/interfaces" I defined the "eth0" interface and aliases for it (eth0: 0, eth0: 1):

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.3.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.3.10

auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
    address 192.168.3.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 192.168.3.3
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

as a result I have

```
# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 38:D2:69:7F:87:8C  
          inet addr:192.168.3.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:175 

eth0:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 38:D2:69:7F:87:8C  
          inet addr:192.168.3.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:175 

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 38:D2:69:7F:87:8C  
          inet addr:192.168.3.3  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:175
```

But now I would like to use my C ++ application to extract only the IP addresses of aliases that are initialized. To do this, I loop in the range 0-9 to see if an alias is active. And then it tries to get an IP address from it.

```
std::string interface_name = "eth0";
    std::vector<std::string> finded_aliases;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        std::string searching_interface_alias = interface_name + ":" + std::to_string(i);
        struct ifreq ifr;
        int sock = socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);
        memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
        strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, searching_interface_alias.c_str());
        ioctl(sock, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ifr);
        close(sock);
        if(!!(ifr.ifr_flags & IFF_UP))
        {
            fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
            char name[searching_interface_alias.length()+1];
            strcpy(name, searching_interface_alias.c_str());
            strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, name, IF_NAMESIZE-1);
            /* Get ip address */
            ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr);
            strncpy(buffor, inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr)->sin_addr), sizeof(buffor));
            std::cout << "Finded alias: " << searching_interface_alias << ", IP: " << buffor << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, I get a list of all aliases on the output

```
Finded alias: eth0:0, IP: 192.168.3.2
Finded alias: eth0:1, IP: 192.168.3.3
Finded alias: eth0:2, IP: 0.0.0.0
Finded alias: eth0:3, IP: 0.0.0.0
Finded alias: eth0:4, IP: 0.0.0.0
Finded alias: eth0:5, IP: 0.0.0.0
Finded alias: eth0:6, IP: 0.0.0.0
Finded alias: eth0:7, IP: 0.0.0.0
Finded alias: eth0:8, IP: 0.0.0.0
Finded alias: eth0:9, IP: 0.0.0.0
```

What could have caused the error? I'd like it to list only active aliases that have ip

Comment: Why not just check to see if the IP doesn't equal 0.0.0.0?

Comment: That's resolved my problem